# Overkill? Using indexOf() to discover contents of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm learning Javascript (fun!) from Beginning Javascript, and a particular example in the book seems like overkill. I know they sometimes do things that aren't strictly best practice - like using document.write - to make the examples extremely easy to understand. But this seems like a case of the opposite: They're using what seems like a very complicated way of doing something, which makes me wonder if there's a reason for it that I don't understand.

See their example below. The purpose of the example is to create two images that will change image source every time you click them. My question pertains to their use of indexOf to search a single string (not an array) - that just seems weird.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 10: Example 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="usa.gif" onclick="changeImg(this)" />
    <img src="mexico.gif" onclick="changeImg(this)" />

    <script>
        var myImages = [
            "usa.gif",
            "canada.gif",
            "jamaica.gif",
            "mexico.gif"
        ];

        function changeImg(that) {
            var newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);

            while (that.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1) {
                newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
            }

            that.src = myImages[newImgNumber];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, instead of using indexOf, it seems a lot easier to write something like:

```
while (that.src == myImages[newImgNumber])) {
    newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
}
```

Would that work? It seems a lot easier for someone to understand, when reviewing the code. Or is there a good reason to do it the way they did it?

**Update:** I think I know the answer, after reflecting on it for a few more minutes. I'm guessing that src will be returned as a long string, not the short string contained in the myImages array. So they need to use indexOf to discover whether the string from myImages is found anywhere inside the src from that.src. Is that right?

Incidentally, their method of creating random numbers bugs me - instead of:

```
newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
```

I prefer:

```
newImgNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
```

The first method won't create an even distribution between the four elements of the array. But maybe they just figure the round vs. floor distinction isn't worth going into in a book for beginners.

Comment: I'd rather do Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length);

Comment: They use `.indexOf()` instead of `==` because the `.src` will return the fully qualified URL, so you need to see if the image name exists within that string.

Comment: ...ECMAScript 6 will have `.endsWith()` for strings, which would be more efficient. Otherwise, you could do `that.src.slice(-myImages[newImgNumber].length) === myImages[newImgNumber]`

Comment: Thanks, @squint! I just realized that, and updated my post accordingly. And right, @Sgnl, I'm getting into the bad habit the book uses in its examples of using numbers when they should use variables or properties. Thanks, gotta try to pick up good habits despite the spoon-feeding of these examples! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`src` IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-src) will return the result of [resolving your relative URL to an absolute one](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#resolve-a-url).

Instead, you can use [`getAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9) to get the [`src` content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src):

```js
var img = document.images[0];
document.body.innerHTML = ''
  +'<dl>'
     +'<dt>src IDL attribute:</dt>'
        +'<dd>' + img.src + '</dd>'
     +'<dt>src content attribute:</dt>'
        +'<dd>' + img.getAttribute('src') + '</dd>'
  +'</dl>';
```

```html
<img src="usa.gif" />
```

Therefore, I would use something like this:

```js
var myImages = [
  "usa.gif",
  "canada.gif",
  "jamaica.gif",
  "mexico.gif"
];
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
  els[i].addEventListener('click', changeImg);
function changeImg() {
  var newImgNumber;
  do {
    newImgNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length);
  } while (this.getAttribute('src') == myImages[newImgNumber]);
  this.src = myImages[newImgNumber];
}
```

```html
<img src="usa.gif" class="myclass" />
<img src="mexico.gif" class="myclass" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great JavaScript library called underscore. http://underscorejs.org/

As well as many other very useful functions this library has a simple contains function that can be used to discover contents of an array. Since you are learning I thought it might be useful to inform you about this library.

Using indexOf to discover contents of a spring is not an overkill and any type of implementation that you might do to discover elements of a collection will do exactly what indexOf does, iterating over the collection till your target element is found. But I personally find syntax of indexOf very cumbersome (!= -1 hate it) so I try to use it as less as I can.

Comment: Thanks, @ralzaul - I haven't gotten into learning about libraries yet. I'll take a look at underscore once I do.